# Response contains nil when trying to get ResponseData using Alamofire 5.0.0

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, frameworks, alamofire

Here is curl request and equivalent being used in swift but always getting nil, I have pasted curl and Alamofire request. btw I am using swift 5.* and Alamofire 5.0.0

```
curl -X GET "https://merchant-samrezikram.klip.ae/merchant/packages?mobileOS=iOS" -H "accept: application/json"
```

When trying to use below code I am getting nil as a response.

```
class NetworkManager: NSObject {



class func getRemoteKlips( requestParams: [String:Any]?,
                           withCompletionHandler: @escaping (_ response:JSON?)->(Void) ) {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type" :"application/json; charset=utf-8"
    ]

    AF.request(APPURL.RemoteKlipPackages,
               method: .get,
               parameters: requestParams,
               encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
               headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseData) in

                if((responseData.response?.statusCode) != nil) {
                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.data as Any)
                    withCompletionHandler(swiftyJsonVar)
                } else {
                    withCompletionHandler(nil)
                }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is a `post` request but you set your method to .get

Comment: Sorry, now we have an update.

Comment: Did you try the request with `Postman` or other apps? it gives me `Could not get any response` error

Comment: I was the same as @Mac3n, couldn't get any data from your endpoint